# A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to do a login, in the user(usuario) table, right after i compile my code i get this "warning" in the Immediate Window, the warning is my topic,then after i hit the Register Button, i get a message saying that i have an error that says: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line one.

My table usuarios(users) has the following fields: idUsuario (PK, NOT NULL, AUTOINCREMENT), Cedula (id) varchar (15), name (Nombre) varchar (10), Apellido (last name) varchar (10), username (Usuario) varchar(10), clave (password) varchar (10). the spanish names are obviously the same of the table and when i created clave i didnt notice it had a lowercase c, that why i didnt put it with uppercase now.

Here is the Code:

Conexion.bv (Module)

```
    Imports MySql.Data    
    Imports MySql.Data.Types     
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient    

    Module Conexion_Bd    
        Public coneccion_servidor As String    
        Public conector As New MySqlConnection    

Public Function coneccion_global() As Boolean
    'Crea la conexion a la base de datos
    Dim estado As Boolean = True
    Try
        coneccion_servidor = ("server=localhost;database=consultorio;user     xxxxx;password=xxxxxx;")
        conector = New MySqlConnection(coneccion_servidor)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        estado = False
    End Try
    Return estado
End Function

Public Sub cerrar()
    conector.Close()
End Sub
```

End Module

Now on datos_ingreso Class

```
    Private _columna_idUsuarios As Integer    
     Private _columna_cedula As String    
     Private _columna_nombre As String    
     Private _columna_apellido As String    
     Private _columna_usuario As String    
     Private _columna_clave As String    

Public Property columna_idUsuarios As Integer
    Get
        Return _columna_idUsuarios
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _columna_idUsuarios = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property columna_cedula As String

    Get
        Return _columna_cedula
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _columna_cedula = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property columna_nombre As String

    Get
        Return _columna_nombre
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _columna_nombre = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property columna_apellido As String

    Get
        Return _columna_apellido
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _columna_apellido = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property columna_usuario As String

    Get
        Return _columna_usuario
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _columna_usuario = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property columna_clave As String

    Get
        Return _columna_clave
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _columna_clave = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

Lastly, on ingreso_uusario_sistema Class

```
    Imports MySql.Data    
    Imports MySql.Data.Types    
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient    
   Public Class ingreso_usuario_sistema    
Private adaptador As New MySqlDataAdapter    

Public Function ingresarUsuarios(ByVal datos As datos_ingreso) As Boolean
    Dim estado As Boolean = True
    Try
        coneccion_global() 'llama a la funcion para crear la conexion la base de datos
        conector.Open() 'Se crea la conexion a la base de datos
        'Utiliza las instancias de la clase de datos de ingreso para poder ingresar los registros a los campos
        '@nombre_campo hace referencia a lo que tiene cada variable para insertar en la Base de Datos
        '@nombre_campo esta hecho en datos_ingresados.
        'No se incluye el id
        adaptador.InsertCommand = New MySqlCommand("insert into usuarios (Cedula, Nombre, Apellido, Usuario, clave) values (@columna_cedula, @columna_nombre, @columna_apellido, @columna_usuario, @columna_clave,)", conector)
        adaptador.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@columna_cedula", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = datos.columna_cedula
        adaptador.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@columna_nombre", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = datos.columna_nombre
        adaptador.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@columna_apellido", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = datos.columna_apellido
        adaptador.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@columna_usuario", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = datos.columna_usuario
        adaptador.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@columna_clave", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = datos.columna_clave
        'conector.Open()
        adaptador.InsertCommand.Connection = conector
        adaptador.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        estado = False
    Finally
        cerrar()
    End Try
    Return estado
End Function
```

End Class

On the Register (Registrar) Button i have the next code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click        
        Dim conexion As New ingreso_usuario_sistema    
        Dim datos As New datos_ingreso    

    datos.columna_cedula = TextBox1.Text
    datos.columna_nombre = TextBox2.Text
    datos.columna_apellido = TextBox3.Text
    datos.columna_usuario = TextBox4.Text
    datos.columna_clave = TextBox5.Text
    If conexion.ingresarUsuarios(datos) Then
        MsgBox("Entry was successful", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Registro Usuarios")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Focus()
    Else
        MsgBox("Entry was not successful", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Registro Usuarios")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Focus()


    End If
End Sub
```

Like i previously said, i get the "warning" first then i get the sql syntax error from the exception and then i get the Entry was not successful message.

Thank you everyone for your time. Please let me know where my mistake was.

Answer (score -1):

I had encountered the same error. I resolved it by using complete connect-string as follows:

```
"server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=rmsprd_owner;port=3307;password=rmsprd"
```

Because at the time of installation I had used port 3307 and not 3306. Please check it for yourself and change the connect string accordingly.